# Database.yml file for activerecord-jdbcvertica-adapter for jruby on rails application

Tags: activerecord, adapter, vertica, jrubyonrails

I am using `activerecord-jdbcvertica-adapter connector` but have no luck creating a new database and migrating tables to vertica database.

My database `yaml` file looks like:

```
development:
     adapter: Vertica
     database: #####
     username: #####
     password: ####
     host: ####
     port: 5433
     encoding: UTF8
```

This throws below error when I do `bundle exec rake db:create db:migrate db:seed`:

```
Rake tasks not supported by 'Vertica' adapter
```

Does anyone know how to use this adapter? Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: I'm not familiar with `activerecord` or `jrubyonrails`, but you can't create more than a single database in Vertica. The logical organization is handled at the schema level.

Comment: .. you typically set up the database when you set up Vertica.